# Problem with linq query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a self referencing table "Product" with the following structure (where D = Draft and A = Approved)

```
ID   ParentID  Status  Name
---------------------------
1    NULL      A       Foo
2    1         A       Foo2
3    NULL      D       Bar
4    1         D       Foo3
```

A row can either be "new" (where ParentID == null) or can be a version of an existing row. So we can see from the table that there are 3 versions for the item "Foo" and only 1 for "Bar".

I need a way of returning the latest versions of each item based on whether the user is able to see only "Approved" items or is able to see "Draft" as well. So for example

Users who can see "D" would have:

```
3    NULL    D
4    1       D
```

The "latest" row for "Foo" and "Bar".

Users who can see "A" would have:

```
2    1       A
```

ie. only the "Approved" versions.

Thanks in advance,

Jose

Comment: How do your classes look like? What LINQ provider are you using? Can you have a longer chain of `ParentID`s? Something like: the parent of 6 is 5 and the parent of 5 is 1.

Comment: Classes have same structure as the table of data. I'm using linq 2 sql. The depth will only ever be 1 (so no child row will have children itself).

Comment: Shouldn't users who can only see "A" only see item 2, as it is the latest approved version of item 1? Or have I misinterpreted your requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Linq query that should work for you:

```
bool hasDraftAccess = false;

var query = DataContext.Records.AsQueryable();

if (!hasDraftAccess) {
    query = query.Where(r => r.Status == 'A');
}

var seriesQuery = query.Select(r => new { Record = r, SeriesID = r.ParentID ?? r.ID });
var latestQuery = seriesQuery.GroupBy(s => s.SeriesID).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(s => s.Record.ID).First());
var resultsQuery = latestQuery.Select(s => s.Record);
var results = resultsQuery.ToArray();
```

Here's what's happening:

1. First, add a WHERE clause to filter out draft records if the user doesn't have access to them
2. Then add a pseudo column called 'SeriesID' that groups all the related versions into that one column. That is, make it easy to group parent and related children.
3. Group the related records and then pick whichever record is most recent
4. Select the Linq Entity from the anonymous type so that it is updatable

I should note that if you have the ability to change your data schema you should consider adding a column called InsertDate or something to that effect. Right now I am assuming that whatever record has the highest ID is the latest. It is often better to add a DateTime field and sort on that instead.

I apologize that this isn't actually using Linq syntax--I prefer fluent coding styles--but it could be easily translated to Linq syntax if you preferred it.

Comment: Thanks - this works great. One thing - I'm having to make a second query to get the full data back from the db using "contains" (using the IDs in your results collection) - is there anyway that this could be done in 1 step? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Totally untested - but something like this might work, if I've understood the question correctly.

Can see approved

```
context.Table.Where(p => p.Status == "A")
```

Can see approved and draft

```
context.Table.Where(p => p.Status == "D" || (p.Status == "A" && !context.Table.Any(q => q.Status == "D" && q.Parent == p.Parent)))
```